# x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm trying to develop face detection using google-mlkit. After setup camera, analyzer, detector etc following docs from google-mlkit https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android, I'm able to detect face. After detect face I'm trying to extract detected face image.

Get detected face boundingBox, extract full bitmap into detected face bitmap using boundingBox. Code below.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mediaImage.getWidth(), mediaImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                                             
YuvToRgbConverter converter = new YuvToRgbConverter(context);
converter.yuvToRgb(mediaImage, bmp);
Bitmap extractedBmp = extractFace(
   bmp,
   (int) (face.getBoundingBox().exactCenterX() / 2),
   (int) (face.getBoundingBox().exactCenterY() / 2),
   face.getBoundingBox().width(),
   face.getBoundingBox().height()
);

private Bitmap extractFace(Bitmap bmp, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Sometimes It's success and sometimes also failed. After debugging I found it's error because of `x + width must be <= bitmap.width()`.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*Exception is correct.*

It happens because face boundingBox can go outside of the image (bitmap).

Also it possible for x and y as well. Try this simple recalculation.

```
private fun extractFace(bmp: Bitmap, x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap? {
    val originX = if (x + width > bmp.width) (bmp.width - width) else x
    val originY = if (y + height > bmp.height) (bmp.height - height) else y
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, originX, originY, width, height)
}
```

*PS: Please check this calculation someone, it should work, thank you*

Answer (score -1):

Could you try util methods provided in the mlkit sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/BitmapUtils.java#L74) to create a bimap from YUV image?

Comment: oke, let me try it first. I will get back to you with the result.

Comment: the link does not answer the question it's about rotation